# How can I generalize Spanish translation of object names' gender?

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, género, artículos, neutralidad-de-género

I am working on the translation of some strings for an app. I have encountered the following problem:

The English version has the following string: "The person uses the", which is used along with an object to form a sentence, e.g. "The person uses the rope."

I can only translate the string to form the appropriate sentence (the objects are given by users). My idea was *"La persona usa la/el"* as a translation in order to form for example: *"La persona usa la/el cuerda"*, which doesn't seem like a proper solution. The problem is I don't know the gender of the object before hand, I can only put together both my string + object provided.

Is there any appropriate wording in Spanish I can use to solve my problem?

**Edit:**

Another possible workaround could be to translate as: "La persona usa" and then add the object as plural i.e. "La persona usa cuerdas".

This doesn't solve my problem, but I just add it to (hopefully) make it clear that my question has nothing to do with programming; I am asking about an appropriate wording in Spanish to hide the gender of an object.

Comment: You could translate the article with the appropriate gender with the noun: la cuerda, el cubo, etc. So instead of translating “the person uses the” translate “the person ises” + “the noun”.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know before hand what the possible object are, those could be literally any word a user wants to store.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be a programming problem, not having to do with speaking or writing the language, or understanding better how it works.

Comment: This looks like a proper "Spanish Language meets Stack Overflow" question. :-) This has to do with a localization issue many programmers meet in their lifes, but cannot be solved without a good knowledge of Spanish. I suppose you don't have access to the source code to modify it?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what's stopping you from implementing @Diego 's solution. Is it that you don't 'know' the gender of the words the person might input? If so, two solutions come to mind: 1) (simpler, but prone to user error) require that the user input the article and the noun 2) (more work, may be less prone to error) consult a database/dictionary of nouns/gender to choose the appropriate article e.g. `user_input = 'mano'; gender = noun_gender_dict[user_input]; if gender == 'F': article = 'la'; else: article = 'el'`

Comment: @walen - "Nothing to do with programming"?  Maybe you mean it's not just about programming.  That would sound less outrageous.  // To me it looks like a fundamental problem with the way the data input to the program was designed.  An interesting problem, perhaps, and certainly it does show a fundamental lack of understanding of how intrinsic gender is to nouns in Spanish.  But I think all we can do is make this clear to OP.  Anything more than that would be programming advice.  I don't think this is the right site to do that in.  Maybe those interested in helping OP could make a chat room.

Comment: @walen, false friend. *Consistent*.

Comment: @DanielDuque this is a generic problem. If you're using PO files to store your translated strings, then you can store context (eg. gender) alongside your words. I imagine there's a similar method for XLIFF files. If you're not yet using PO or XLIFF to help manage your translations then I recommend that you start, rather than trying to create your own solution to a common problem :-)

Comment: I realize my answer deals more than a bit with programming, but that's only because you actually need an algorithm to deal with nouns in Spanish (and algorithm != computer program), so I think it's on-topic to describe it in broad terms. The bits about programming terms are only a plus.

Comment: @aparente001 A good start to explaining how intrinsic gender is to nouns in Spanish to a programmer is, I think, speaking a bit in programmer's terms. Describing the actual implementation would be, as you say, off-topic.

Comment: @walen, if the subject is rhetoric then the cognate is fine. But if you look at the example in MW where the subject is a person, it's a different meaning. "*Let's be coherent*" means roughly "*Let's use real words and clear grammar and communicate our ideas to our hearers*". OED Spanish-English lists *consistent* for *coherente* with gloss *consecuente*, and has the examples *hay que actuar con coherencia* => *you have to be consistent* and *la falta de coherencia entre lo que predican y lo que hacen* => *the lack of consistency between what they preach and what they do*.

Comment: @pablodf76 - Programming is more than writing code.  First you define the problem, develop an algorithm, plan your input and output, draw a flow chart or write some pseudocode, choose your data names, write some documentation, then write your code.  Then you still get to debug.  Maybe I left some things out.

Comment: @walen - The question here would not exist if the OP weren't having difficulty with the design of their computer program.

Comment: @aparente001 Would you consider the question valid if I were translating a book instead of an app? I don't understand why this has caused so much controversy.

Comment: Daniel, keep in mind that right now there's only one close vote for your question.  I'm in a minority of one. // I can't imagine that someone would sit down and translate a book, let's say from one gendered language to another, without knowing the genders of the nouns to be translated, or the genders of the translated nouns.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your question was proposed for closing as being about programming rather than about Spanish, but I think this is a valid question:

> *Is there any appropriate wording in Spanish I can use to* [refer to an object without specifying its grammatical gender]*?*

There are some ways of achieving this. Some of them will look more unnatural than others, but all are valid Spanish.

- Use plural names.
  You already mentioned this one. I guess you did so because in English, plural names don't need an article... but that's just English. In Spanish, both singular and plural names use articles by default, so it's not like by using plural names you could get away with it. However, it may work.

  > La persona usa cuerdas.
  >   La persona usa cubos.
- Drop the article altogether.
  Using plurals is actually just a variation on this one. Yes, Spanish names are usually accompanied by their article to provide/confirm gender and number information, but you can drop it when not needed (literary language sometimes does this). It will come out as somewhat "robotic speech" if there's no adjective or determinant to supply that info, but it is still valid Spanish.

  > La persona usa cuerda.
  >   La persona usa cubo.
- **Use a colon instead of an article.**
  There's one place where articles are usually omitted: enumerations. By turning the sentence into a one-item enumeration, you can afford to drop the article (and thus the gender) while still sounding natural or, at least, not as unnatural as the other options. And it also works with plurals, proper names, or whatever the user wrote.

  > La persona usa: cuerda.
  >   La persona usa: cubo.
  >   La persona usa: semillas.
  >   La persona usa: vendajes.
  >   La persona usa: Rust-eze™.

You probably saw the last option being used in video games. It is the most natural-sounding and the one I'd recommend.

---

You mention that using the plural form is not a valid solution for your specific case. I'm guessing that's because you still would need to know how to form the plural of user`. Just wanted to mention that the rules to form the plural are not that complicated, you could probably implement them if you needed to.

Of course, there are programmatic ways of getting the actual gender of a word, so you can adequately pick one of *el, la, los, las* instead of trying to hide them; but answering that would be off-topic.

Comment: To me the `:` solution seems the cleanest.

Answer (score 1):

Where do you get the data for the user-given nouns from? Nouns in Spanish are described by their lexical form (the word that is the noun itself in the singular) and their gender; there's also a rule the shifts the stress when forming the plurals of certain (very few) words.

Your program should have a Spanish dictionary (better yet, a noun-only dictionary), and said dictionary should contain the information about the noun's gender. That is, it cannot be just a list of valid nouns in Spanish, but also include the information found in Spanish dictionaries (where the entry for *cuerda*, for example, specifies it's a feminine noun).

There are, I believe, free dictionaries that you can download, parse and turn into such a list as you need. Then you need to parse what the user entered. Of course this is not that simple. The dictionary will tell you to use *el* for masculine nouns and *la* for feminine nouns. But feminine nouns beginning with a vowel will take *el* instead. If the user enters something ending in *-s* it's very likely to be a plural noun, but in that case your program will have to remove the *-s* and check. And so on. But for the vast majority of nouns, assigning them the correct article based on gender and number should be straightforward.

There's no appropriate nice-looking way of hiding the gender of a Spanish noun in a sentence like the one you give in your example. That is, you **can** produce simple sentences with nouns but no articles or adjectives and thus without gender agreement, but that's a very restricted set of possible sentences.

Comment: I agree with the concept. As a computer science major and wannabe philology amateur, I think the best one can do is treating nouns as objects, with a `gender` property and a `definite()` method, or even a more general `parse()` method with parameters to tell definiteness, gender, etc. These methods should (obviously) return a string.